# python np.where is weird in indexing specific range

Tags: python, numpy

Hi I am starting with python..

I found something that is not good to understand for me about using np.where() in python

```
aaa = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
np.where(aaa[3:5] > 4)
```

what I expected:`[4]`

what I got: `(array([1]),)`

Anybody Help please?
Thank you for reading

Comment: Can you explain your criterion in plain english? Then we can write the correct expression for it later... what is it that you want to do exactly?

Comment: In python `np.where` is a function.  Function arguments are evaluated before being passed. Test `aa>4` and choose values between 3 and 5 after.

Comment: I solved this with [x+3 for x in np.where(aaa[3:5] >4)[0].tolist()], It gets [4]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are index slicing aaa -> `aaa[3:5]` this new array looks like `array([4, 5])` and where this new array is greater than 4 is at position 1 (as arrays start at 0).

In addition, np.where returns a tuple when only a condition is given:

> If only condition is given, return the tuple condition.nonzero(), the
> indices where condition is True

hence the result being a tuple:

```
(array([1]),)
```

Replace the np.where line with

```
np.where(aaa>4)[0][0]
```

Comment: thank you so much. then is there anyway that get  [4] instead of [1]?

Comment: thank you. what i am looking for is somthing that aaa[3:5] > 4 get 4

Answer (score 1):

It is correct,

In `np.where(...)` documentation we see, that it calls `np.nonzero(...)` when `x,y` are omitted, as in your case.

What `np.nonzero(...)` does

> Return the indices of the elements that are non-zero.

And it returns a position of `True` here.

```
>>> aaa[3:5] > 4
array([False,  True])
```

Comment: thank you so much. then is there anyway that get  [4] instead of [1]?

Answer (score 1):

The explanation for this phenomenon is as follows:

When you slice the original array, via `aaa[3:5]` a new array is returned. `np.where` returns the indices for matched entries in the array that you pass to it. So, to **see** the actual result, you need to use the same *new* array:

```
import numpy as np

aaa = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
print(aaa[3:5])    # remember, array index count starts from 0
# [4 5]

idx = np.where(aaa[3:5] > 4)   # we are NOT looking in the original array
print(idx)
# (array([1]),)

# So, only one element matches the criteria in the given array, its index in the NEW array is returned

print(aaa[3:5][idx])
#[5]
```

Remember, the index returned by the `np.where` in this case should not be used to fetch the element from the *original array*, but, only from the *new array*.

Comment: `what I expected:[4]` why would you expect that? I mean what was your rationale?

Comment: thank you so much. then is there anyway that get  [4] instead of [1]?

Comment: your condition is `>4`, why would you get `4` in the first place?

Comment: I mean, I am familiar with R, so in R which(aaa[3:5] >4) result is 5. note that R is starts with 1

Comment: right, so you are getting the index for element 5, but, in the _new_ **2 element array**. the `array([1], )` is the index, not the value. To get the value, see the last print statement of my code!

Comment: Thanks alot, I solved this with [x+3 for x in np.where(aaa[3:5] >4)[0].tolist()]